# Replacing UITableView with UIPopOverController

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uipopovercontroller

I have a UITableView that does not take up the whole screen of the iPad.  The current view I have it in is the datasource and delegate for the UITableView.  Now I want to replace the current UITableView with a UIPopOverController.  From the examples I see online, it seems like most people create a new class that subclasses UITableView, and present that instance in the UIPopOverController.  In my case, since my current viewController is the datasource and delegate already, would my steps need to be:

(1) create a new class, subclassing UITableViewController
(2) make this class the datasource and delegate
(3) present an instance of this class in the current viewController where my UITableView was?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

make a new navigation controller and present it with the rootView as the table

```
- (IBAction)seeFavorites{
NSLog(@"Favorites accessed");
if([self.popOverController isPopoverVisible])
{


    [self.popOverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
    return;
}

UINavigationController *favNav = [[UINavigationController alloc]
                                  initWithRootViewController:favoritesView];


self.popOverController = [[[UIPopoverController alloc] 
                           initWithContentViewController:favNav] autorelease];


[popOverController presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:revealFavorites permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
favoritesView.view.frame = CGRectMake(10, 10, 310, 320);

favoritesView.title = @"Favorites";

[favoritesView.tableView reloadData];


if (![self.popOverController isPopoverVisible]) {
    [favNav release];

}

}
```

to make an outlet:

in "File1"

```
@class File2;
@interface FirstViewControlleriPad : UIViewController

{
//code
File2 *file2Outlet;

}
@property (nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet File2 *file2Outlet;
@end
```

in the .m file

```
 #import "File2.h"
@implementation File1
@synthesize file2Outlet
```

in the appDelegate.h

```
#import "File1.h"
#import "File2.h"

@interface AppDelegate : NSObject  {
//...code for appDelegate
File1 *file1;
File2 *file2;
}
@property (nonatomic,retain) File1 *file1;
@property (nonatomic,retain) File2 *file2;
@end
```

in the appDelegate.m

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions{

file1 = [[File1 alloc]init];
file2 = [[File2 alloc]init];
file1.file2Outlet = file2;
[file1 release];
[file2 release];
```

Comment: My favoritesView is an instance of UITableView.  The initWithRootViewController is looking for an instance of UIViewController right?

Comment: favoritesView is an outlet to one of my files. I'll update my answer with how to create the outlet.